# NetBeans & Executable JARs

Tags: java, deployment, netbeans, jar

New to NetBeans dev here. When I first created my project and began compiling, I noticed that NetBeans had automatically created a `dist/` directory under my project root and was creating an Executable JAR in that directory.

I've now been developing for several weeks, and added many resource files to my project, including a system log file, an embedded SQLite database, and several properties files. These are files that my program (a Swing app) needs to read/write from at runtime in order to function correctly.

I just noticed this morning that the Executable JAR in my `dist/` directory is several weeks old, and that compiling my project doesn't update it.  I am wondering if that's because there are now all these new resource files and NetBeans doesn't know how/where to package them for the automatically-created Executable JAR.

Does this mean that I'll have to tweak the build.xml myself? Or is there a NetBeans dialog I can get to where I can specify where to pacakge everything? And if NetBeans should be doing this automatically, what could be the reason that it stopped creating the JAR for me, and what can I do to force this functionality again?

I went into **Project Properties >> Packaging** and made sure that the *JAR file* directory was still `dist/MyProgram.jar` and that the checkbox *Build JAR after compiling* was still checked, so obviously something else is either breaking the build or messing with NB.

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: What version of netbeans? Hmm I have the same issue issue but never really thought more about it. I just Clean and Build whenever I want a /dist.

Comment: harper89 - That's the answer I was looking for! Quick, turn your comment into an answer so I can check it! And thanks!

Comment: @Mara Just out of curiousity, exactly how are you compiling your application that it doesn't build the dist?  Are you just running it from inside the IDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If "Compile on Save" is enabled, then your .jar file will only be generated when you do a "Clean & Build" (Just "Build" is not available when "Compile on Save" is enabled)

Answer (score 0):

You need to Clean and Build within netbeans to update the file within your /dist directory.

I use Netbeans 7.0 and this solution works for me.

Comment: Not entirely correct.  A simple "Build" will also create the distribution file (without the pain of recompiling the entire project).  Running the project from inside the IDE will not though.

Comment: True I was just adding my answer as the OP suggested. A "dirty" build would also get the job done.